# Django ManyToMany Relationship with Through model filtering

Tags: sql, django

Suppose I have the following setup (models.py)

```py
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(....)


class EventInfo(models.Model):
 attending = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
 person = models.ForeignKey('Person')

class Event(models.Model):
  start = models.DateTimeField(....)
  ....
  participants = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=EventInfo)
```

I am aware of the fact that `participants` is in fact an object of type `RelatedManager`, and i can query it like that:

```py
e = Event.objects.get(...)
e.participants.filter(name="John") #gives me the Person named 'John'
```

But what I am missing is an intuitive way to (e.G.) filter for all persons that are attending my Event, by making use of the specified through-model.
I know I can do one of the following things:

```py
e = Event.objects.get(...)
# would give me a queryset of EventInfo objects, but theres no easy way to get all persons from that:
qs = EventInfo.objects.filter(event=e, attending=True) 

# would give me in fact all persons, but seems rather unintuitive:
qs = Person.objects.filter(eventinfo__event=e, eventinfo__attending=True)

# same thing, quite unintuitive having to query from "the other side"
e.participants.filter(eventinfo__attending=True)
```

What I would like to write:

```py
e = Event.objects.get(...)
e.participants.filter(attending=True)
```

which would give me a list of persons. This is not possible because `participants` filters on `Person` and not on `EventInfo`
 Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Well what you need to do here is reverse foreign key lookup.
So to access an attribute of EventInfo via participants you will have to do something like this.

```
e.participants.eventinfo_set.filter(attending=True)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
e.participants.eventinfo_set.filter(attending=True) ?

Comment: I am not quite suire how to get to the eventinfo_set from the participants. participants is a Manager so it has no fields, right?

Comment: no it didnt work, but im not sure if I am doing it right... participants is a RelatedManager and imo therefore does not have access to fields from the Person model. Am I wrong?

Comment: AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'eventinfo_set'
this is to be expected...